# Looping through a list to change the src of an image

Tags: javascript

So what is want to do is when the user clicks a button and then javascript will loop through a list and change the source of an image for every item in the list:

Javascript (image addresses are completly random):

```
images = ["https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ogw/AAEL6sjw9dduiRogTxPK6DINwgbrrbDQvTYCZIF5L7BPjw=s32-c-mo", "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTTAdKB4YazVymOswPFKMfUjCcJSRhr6e1QxOEOeL6P-9pxChlQHs7H8foV8AKbIKEa3jc&usqp=CAU", "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/9Dx0SmLSLdctuysuyEB2zRvcGAv6vda9EyaAGEt4T2paouQr763BQcKPTf86Jdj-8BXqXxNUGqBKJBIn=w544-h544-s-l90-rj"];
function my_function(){
   for(x in images){
      document.getElementById("image").src = x;
   }
}
```

here is my html:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <button onclick="my_function()">clkdfafd</button>
    <img id="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQm1NxjkLYfAFElYwTFN848roKIhwWhBgJT0w&usqp=CAU">
    </body>
</html>
```

But when ever i run this i always get the image that shows when the image you want doesn't show up:

[image]

Comment: don't do that, load all images, and flip display on/off, and not load /unload images all the time

Comment: You shouldn't use `for-in` with iterables, instead use any array methods like `forEach`, `for-of`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are using `for (x in images)`. This construction makes the variable `x` to contain the index of the array (`0`, `1`, `2`, etc) instead of the value as you are expecting.

To fix it, you just need to change the `in` to `of` like this:

```js
for (x of images) { ... }
```

Alternatively, you can keep the `in` and index the array when consuming it instead:

```js
for (x in images) {
  document.getElementById("image").src = images[x];
}
```

Take a look at this working code:

```js
images = ["https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ogw/AAEL6sjw9dduiRogTxPK6DINwgbrrbDQvTYCZIF5L7BPjw=s32-c-mo", "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTTAdKB4YazVymOswPFKMfUjCcJSRhr6e1QxOEOeL6P-9pxChlQHs7H8foV8AKbIKEa3jc&usqp=CAU", "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/9Dx0SmLSLdctuysuyEB2zRvcGAv6vda9EyaAGEt4T2paouQr763BQcKPTf86Jdj-8BXqXxNUGqBKJBIn=w544-h544-s-l90-rj"];

function my_function(){
   for(x of images){
      document.getElementById("image").src = x;
   }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <button onclick="my_function()">clkdfafd</button>
    <img id="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQm1NxjkLYfAFElYwTFN848roKIhwWhBgJT0w&usqp=CAU">
    </body>
</html>
```

--- Edit ---

As [Carsten Massmann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2610061/carsten-massmann) pointed out, my answer so far will only fix the issue about the images not displaying. If you want to rotate the images every time you press the button, you will need to keep track of which was the last image you displayed (or the next image you need to display).

In order to do this, you can declare a variable with the index in the array for the next image so, when the function runs, you know you just need to use this index and prepare the next one for the next run.

Here is an example:

```js
let nextIndex = 0;
const images = ["https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ogw/AAEL6sjw9dduiRogTxPK6DINwgbrrbDQvTYCZIF5L7BPjw=s32-c-mo", "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTTAdKB4YazVymOswPFKMfUjCcJSRhr6e1QxOEOeL6P-9pxChlQHs7H8foV8AKbIKEa3jc&usqp=CAU", "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/9Dx0SmLSLdctuysuyEB2zRvcGAv6vda9EyaAGEt4T2paouQr763BQcKPTf86Jdj-8BXqXxNUGqBKJBIn=w544-h544-s-l90-rj"];

function my_function(){
   document.getElementById("image").src = images[nextIndex];
   nextIndex = (nextIndex + 1) % images.length;
   // The `%` corresponds to the modulo operation which will
   // take the reminder of dividing the value with the length
   // of the array. This will allow the looping feature.
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <button onclick="my_function()">clkdfafd</button>
    <img id="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQm1NxjkLYfAFElYwTFN848roKIhwWhBgJT0w&usqp=CAU">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nicely explained! You solved the problem of an image src not showing up. However, there is still the issue that, as soon, as the button is clicked, _all_ the strings in the array are assigned to  `image.src`, one after the other, but _only the last one_ will be visible. I assume OP wants to _step through_ the array with each button click.

Comment: @CarstenMassmann you are right. Let me update the answer :-) Sometimes it's unclear if you should just fix the immediate problem or provide a more opinionated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I liked the way @CarlosV2 explained and solved the problems above. Case solved!

However, as so often, I started wondering about alternative solutions and came up with this one that actually changes (rotates) the content of the `images` array. This might or might not be what you want but it would also result in the same user experience:

```js
const images = ["https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ogw/AAEL6sjw9dduiRogTxPK6DINwgbrrbDQvTYCZIF5L7BPjw=s32-c-mo", "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTTAdKB4YazVymOswPFKMfUjCcJSRhr6e1QxOEOeL6P-9pxChlQHs7H8foV8AKbIKEa3jc&usqp=CAU", "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/9Dx0SmLSLdctuysuyEB2zRvcGAv6vda9EyaAGEt4T2paouQr763BQcKPTf86Jdj-8BXqXxNUGqBKJBIn=w544-h544-s-l90-rj"],
      img=document.getElementById("image");

document.querySelector("button").onclick=()=>images.push(img.src=images.shift())
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
    <button>click here to change the image</button>
    <img id="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQm1NxjkLYfAFElYwTFN848roKIhwWhBgJT0w&usqp=CAU">
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is yet another (scalable) version that would be able to handle multiple `img` and `button` instances without changing the `images` array and also without any globally visible state variables:

```js
const images = ["https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ogw/AAEL6sjw9dduiRogTxPK6DINwgbrrbDQvTYCZIF5L7BPjw=s32-c-mo", "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTTAdKB4YazVymOswPFKMfUjCcJSRhr6e1QxOEOeL6P-9pxChlQHs7H8foV8AKbIKEa3jc&usqp=CAU", "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/9Dx0SmLSLdctuysuyEB2zRvcGAv6vda9EyaAGEt4T2paouQr763BQcKPTf86Jdj-8BXqXxNUGqBKJBIn=w544-h544-s-l90-rj"];
document.querySelectorAll(".image").forEach(img=>{
  img.idx=0;
  img.previousElementSibling.onclick=()=>img.src=images[img.idx++%images.length]
})
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <button>click here to change the image</button>
    <img class="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQm1NxjkLYfAFElYwTFN848roKIhwWhBgJT0w&usqp=CAU">

    <button>click here to change the image</button>
    <img class="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQm1NxjkLYfAFElYwTFN848roKIhwWhBgJT0w&usqp=CAU">

    <button>click here to change the image</button>
    <img class="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQm1NxjkLYfAFElYwTFN848roKIhwWhBgJT0w&usqp=CAU">
  </body>
</html>
```

The current example relies on the fact that the button is the immediately preceding element of each `.image`-image. This type of relative selection might need to be changed in a "real life" application.

Comment: Oh! Nice one! This is a good alternative to keep the state within the array itself. Also, I like how this is the array-equivalent of `i++` :-D